# How to add a scroll view in storyboard visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-2019

I have looked everywhere on the internet and can't find the answer to how to add a scroll view in storyboard visual studio 2019. I know that there is a UI scroll view and that your suppose to put a view on top of that although I can't figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunately , current version of visual studio can not do that in storyboard . Therefore , I suggest that using C# code to implement it . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiscrollview?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12 This feature will come in the later version of vs .

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Xcode to design? Just right click on story board and open with Xcode. And check this basic tutorial of UIscrollview.

https://youtu.be/_Qn3UGad3lg

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more specific, I am using a pc and I am connected to a mac.

Comment: just copy your storyboard separately and use it in mac for design.. and xcode is far better then the visual studio in terms of design. so i strongly recommended to use xcode..

Comment: The reason I have been using a pc and visual studio because my mac is really old and slow. I have been able to do almost everything I wanted in the xamarin designer although this is the first time I have been having trouble. Do you know how to add a scroll view in visual studio or would you be able to play around with it because I am completely stuck.

Comment: it's better you to use the table view.. scroll view is bit hard to handle the scroll and it's size and so many things you have to manage.
just create a table with the static cell.. add whatever complement you want to add and that's it. scroll will work automatically. just try with your requirement. if you are facing issue with that then just let me know. i'll make example for you.

Comment: i have sent a link but it was deleted somwhow..
please download the sample code from the below URL.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14J26wYgmnanMbLqU2xC6S-vtg_Bf5koq/view?usp=sharing