# Scroll view not scrolling in storyboard

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, scrollview

I have the following scroll view although when I run the simulator I am not able to scroll. I have vertical constraints set for the content items, any idea why this is?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a scroll view in storyboard visual studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234502/how-to-add-a-scroll-view-in-storyboard-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: @Jason I was the one who wrote that question, I am using a pc so I can't open with xcode

Comment: @coder123 Hi , suggest that using coding to create ScorllView in Xamarin iOS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiscrollview?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) .

Answer (score 0):

can you provide your constraint details? i hope you have added one view on top of the scrollview.

Comment: would you be able to just screen record a quick video of you adding a working scroll view in visual studio.